# Multi-homed NIC still automatically registering addresses in DNS after unchecking option

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows

I have a Windows Server 2008 box that has one NIC. I have two IP's assigned to that NIC manually. I have gone to `ncpa.cpl` and opened the Advanced IP Configuration -> DNS menu and unchecked "Register this connection's addresses in DNS." Despite my efforts Windows is intent on disobeying and every night at 12 it re-registers the DNS entries. I would like to configure a static A record for this server in DNS and be done with it but it does not listen to me. How can I make Windows behave?

Comment: Is your DHCP server configured to register clients on their behalf?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, the address is manually assigned to the server.

Comment: OK. Perhaps that setting requires a restart to take effect then?

Comment: Certainly sounds like it's worth a try... I'll have to wait till tonight but sounds legit

Comment: Is this server a DNS server?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, and eventually opened a call with MS Premier support to get an answer.
The "solution" is described here.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975808

After you apply the hotfix, you can run `NETSH` to disable DNS registration for specific adapters:

```
Netsh int ipv4 add address <Interface Name> <ip address> <subnet mask> skipassource=true
```

Trick to remember: After you have used NETSH to set the SKIPASSOURCE param, do not use the GUI to modify anything on the same NIC. If you do use the GUI to change anything, you need to reapply the SKIPASSOURCE parameter with NETSH.